# when ever i open storyboard in xcode 8.3.3 it's automatically start build it's taking 2-3 min. how to stop this?

Tags: ios, xcode8

Every time when i open storyboard in xcode 8.3.3 it's automatically start building it's taking 2-3 min every time, and that time xcode also slow. how to stop this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn off automatically refresh views..

[image]

Comment: Cool. Then you can select 'Refresh All Views' when you need to